# PreventDefault Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a preventDefault action on some hyperlinks to prevent them being activated, instead calling some ajax. However it doesn't seem to work.

The code I am using is as follows:
I have the following code:

```
    $("#" + container_id + " a[id^=read_more_link]").click(function(event){
        alert($(this).html());
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now what is interesting is the alert box fires so its definitely registering the click event, however it does not seem to recognise the preventDefault() call.

**I tried a simple test simplifying my code and it still does not work:**

```
<a id="read_more_link" data-article_id="1" href="news/1">Read More</a>

    $("#read_more_link").on("click", function(event){
        alert("test");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Alert box fires but then page follows the link still.

**Note: It works If I use 'Return False' but not with preventDefault**

Comment: How do you think `preventDefault` call should be recognised? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Can you show your related markup? It is possible that your attribute selector is wrong.

Comment: I would just add that if you put some valid value in the 'href' attribute of the anchor and the anchor doesn't take you to that url once clicked, it is working properly.

Comment: Are you still being taken to the destination in the link? Please explain "doesn't work."

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yP7BA/

Comment: I am doing exactly the same as the ones people have posted here but its not working. Im using Firefox

Comment: $("#read_more_link").on("click", function(event){
  alert("test");
  event.preventDefault();
 });

Answer (score 1):

Here you are!

```
function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rXCcB/2/

Edit: As [11684](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087848/11684) correctly pointed out, a detailed explanation would be helpful.

Some browsers recognize `e` as a `window.event`, which contains all the information on an event; in this case, the click event you're trying to manipulate. A few other browsers don't, so what happens at the first step in the function is a normalization across all browsers on the definition of `e`. End result is that every reference to `e` points to `window.event`, at which point you can safely use `e.preventDefault()`, knowing that all browsers understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Perhaps add an explanation so future readers could learn a bit more? Using code you don't understand seems to me a bad practice.

Comment: jQuery normalizes the `event`, this is not needed.

Comment: I see. I don't use libraries so I'm not aware of the auto-magic that jQuery uses for its functions. Provided a library-agnostic method, for question author's benefit though.

Comment: I normally use 'e' rather event myself but I wanted to make it easier for everyone to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are preventing the default action of the link which has some parent, then your selector should be like this:

my html is:

```
<p id='aaa'>
   <a id='read_more_link' href='#'>adf</a>
</p>
```

the jquery:

```
var container_id = $('#aaa');
$("a[id^='read_more_link']", container_id).click(function(event) {
   alert($(this).html());
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EEZEe/

see if this help you out.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one easier, and one better way of doing it:

Easier:

```
$("#" + container_id + " a[id^=read_more_link]").click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    return false;
});
```

No need to use the event parameter, and no need to call a function.

Better:

Use a button instead of a link:

```
<p id='aaa'>
   <button id='read_more_link' type='button'>adf</button>
</p>
```

Then you don't run into this problem, since a button is made for exactly this - events. Links are made for linking, and `return false` or `preventDefault()` are, while they may work,  workarounds.

Comment: Your jQuery selected might be improved as well. But thats not really the issue here.

Comment: Make sure the button isn't in a `<form>`.  It'll try to submit the form (unless you add `type="button"`)

Comment: Exactly. Hence "type='button'".

Comment: Return false does work but I would prefer to use the proper way.

Comment: @Nuvolari: `return false;` is the proper way.

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold: I totally noticed you already had that >.<